# How to prevent QAudioInput from automatically boosting the master volume to 100%?

Tags: qt, audio-recording, volume, pulseaudio, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to use Qt5 Multimedia to record audio with QAudioInput. I noticed, however, that when my `QAudioInput` starts, it raises the master volume of my sound device to 100%.

How can I prevent QAudioInput from changing the master volume?

My current development platform is Linux with PulseAudio (with flat audio disabled).

This is how I'm using `QAudioInput`:

```
QAudioDeviceInfo device_info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();

QAudioFormat format;
format.setSampleRate(44100);
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleSize(16) ;
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);

std::cout << device_info.deviceName().toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
QAudioInput *default_device = new QAudioInput(device_info, format);

QIODevice *default_io_device = default_device->start();
```

Comment: Since I have observed similar behaviour and after trying several options I have concluded it is a bug in Qt and hence I opened a bug report - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47148

Answer (score 0):

There is a `QAudioInput.setVolume()` method if you have not seen. Having said that, I tried using `QAudioRecorder.setVolume()` and Qt is telling me - "Setting volume while recording is not supported".